# Redirect after submit ASP.NET

Tags: c#, redirect, webforms

is there a way to redirect to page, after submit a form, and in the redirected page, there will be an message that will be posted only if the user redirected after submut?

example:

If submit a form in the page named **`"Register.aspx"`** I want to redirect to **`"Login.aspx"`** page, and ONLY if I was redirectd after I sign up there will be a message 
"You just have to login now".

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: ASP.NET Session State Overview = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: It's very easy to do, but, you should try something first.

Comment: Thank you, i'm just learning ASP.NET so it all very new for me, so I don't really know how to do it right now

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Learning ASP.NET *Web Forms*? That's been a legacy technology for several years, and was crap already when it was introduced 10 years ago. Learn a modern ASP.NET variant instead.

Comment: @bzlm Yes, I know it old technology (PHP much better) but I have to do specific project in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Register.aspx page, write the message to Session, then in Login.aspx, check for the Session variable and display the message if it exists and optionally remove the variable from Session to prevent further displays. Alternatively, you could redirect to Login.aspx?showMessage=1 and check for the showMessage variable in the QueryString and display based on that.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Don't forget to mark it as the answer if you feel it is.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Session key to save the state to know the user when He/She visit the Login page and check if it exists Show the relevant message.

Answer (score 1):

[Url Referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) will let you know what page you came from.  You can also use query string.  It can be done with session, but personally I avoid Session and ViewState at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect, use:

```
Response.Redirect("someUri");
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx

For controlling the message, just use a query string or session variable.